# Play animation state's clip from particular time or fram

Tags: unity, c#, animation, animation-states

I have a controller where i have a animation state. I want to play that animation clip from specified frame to specifed end frame. is this possible?

here is the snap shot of the controller
[image]
currently i am simply switching tow application using bool. I want to transition to paritcualr state but want to play its particular frame or time duration as a clip.

```
public Animator talkingAvatarAnimator;
    public bool isPlayHandGesture;

    void Update () {
        talkingAvatarAnimator.SetBool("isPlayHandGesture", isPlayHandGesture);

    }
```

Comment: You want to alternate between 2 animations mid-play or something else?

Comment: I want to play my second state which is actually working correctly but i dont want to play it from beginnig to end. I want to play its specified frames from middle of the animation.

Comment: Depending on how you decide what the starting point should be you can try https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.Play (look at normalized time) or next link https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/142206/how-to-avoid-spaghetti-in-the-animator may be of help too (look my answer about blend trees).