# replacing an animation with another one - unity

Tags: unity, animation, animator

In Unity, When moving from one animation to another, I want the second animation to not start from the beginning and be a continuation of the previous one (For example, if there is a change in the third second, the second animation starts from the third second)

is there any way to do this by Animator settings or using a script?

Comment: [BlendTrees](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/142206/how-to-avoid-spaghetti-in-the-animator/142208#142208) may help you.

Comment: @Nikaas I can't see what the relation between these two questions is. I don't have any issues about switching with animation is currently playing, rather I want transitions to not start the second clip from the first frame (all animation clips have the same length by the way)

Comment: This is exactly what BlendTrees do, as a side effect they solve messy animator states. The questions are different but BlendTrees solve both issues.